# Error when doing a global uninstall of create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm trying to remove the global create-react-app but i'm running into the following error. any help would be appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFrIb.png)

Comment: Try with `sudo`

Comment: Ajeet for the win!